# How can i pass command line arguments to a java spring docker container

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I am using one value attribute tag inside my spring boot application.Instead of passing value from the environment properties file, I want to pass the value at run time while running my docker image.

This is the variable which my application is using inside my controller class.
@Value("${test.path}")
private String testpath;

**-----Below is my command----** 
docker run -p 8090:8090 -e "test.path"=abc docker-spring-boot

When I try to run the above command the command throws error
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dazzling_kepler (3fc1d067c024443a9f92b8493060079c23a4d11b3662695fc60f3a9366de0247): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8090: unexpected error Permission denied.

Is there any way to pass these argument values at run time ?

Comment: The error is not regarding environment variables, seems you dont have permission to bind to port 8090. Try running it again but with `sudo`.

Comment: If i remove the -e "test.path"=abc then there is no error there is some issue with the extra parameter only

Comment: Below is my error while running command with the value attribute at runtime org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 's3BucketController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'test.path' in value "${test.path}"

Comment: Find out the answer mistake from my side value attribute name was mismatch